# How can I select feature, except null values?

Tags: qgis

I want to select feature except NULL values.

In the past, when I using ArcGIS, I used 'select by attributes', and type like 'NOT "field name"=NULL'

But now, in QGIS, it doesn't work.
Just like ArcGIS, i used 'select by attributes', and type like 'NOT "field name"=NULL'
But it select nothing.

How can I select feature except NULL values, using 'select by attributes' in QGIS?

Comment: Where did Null values came from in the first place?

Answer (score 5):

In QGIS you need to write the following:

```
"FieldName" is not null
```

Where "FieldName" is the name of your field that contains null values.

Comment: @JungTaeJun Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: @JungTaeJun https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers